# Add JSONObject to JSONArray java with add attribute

Tags: java, json, servlets

This is my servlet code. I want add my json object values into a json array.I  used `add` method for that  but I'm getting an error. How to add that object to my array? Is there any mistake in my code?

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
     throws ServletException, IOException {

    try {
        Session ses = HibernateSession.getSession();
        Criteria cr1 = HibernateSession.createCriteria(ses, Product.class);
        cr1.add(Restrictions.eq("Status", "Active"));
        List<Product> plist = cr1.list();

        JSONArray ja1 = new JSONArray();
        for (Product product : plist) {
            JSONObject jo1 = new JSONObject();
            jo1.put("image", product.getProductImages());
            jo1.put("name", product.getName());
            jo1.put("price", product.getPrice());

            ja1.add(jo1);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: what kind of error?

Comment: not error. cannot use add

Comment: maybe ja1 vs js1

Comment: image upload.cannot find symbol

Comment: maybe use ja1.put() (assuming you are using org.json.JSONArray)

Comment: what json library are you using?

Comment: import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

Comment: @PoornaGamage There should be an error. In fact it's an compile-error "_cannot find symbol: method add()_".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the libraries which you are using.

If you are using `org.json.JSONArray` then it should be `put()` but if you are using `org.json.simple.JSONArray` it's `add()`.

---

I bet you are using `org.json.JSONArray`. So try,

```
ja1.put(jo1);
```

Comment: what is the different  between org.json. & org.json.simple.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `put()` instead of `add()` ;)